# I want to log the logs of a controller in a new log file

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

In Symfony 5.4, and by using monolog 3.8. I want to log the request handling of a specifique controller, in a new log file . for my case is citiesController
this my monolog config.

```
monolog:
    channels:
        - deprecation 
        - cities_controller

when@dev:
    monolog:
        handlers:
            main:
                type: stream
                path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
                level: debug
                channels: ["!event"]
            # uncomment to get logging in your browser
            # you may have to allow bigger header sizes in your Web server configuration
            #firephp:
            #    type: firephp
            #    level: info
            #chromephp:
            #    type: chromephp
            #    level: info
            cities_controller_log:
                type: stream
                path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/CitiesController.log"
                level: debug
                channels: ['cities_controller']
            console:
                type: console
                process_psr_3_messages: false
                channels: ["!event", "!doctrine", "!console"]
```

I expect to get the logs of the cities controller in a new file called citiesController.log
but as far as I check the log file doesn't get created .
I get the logs in var/dev.logs

Comment: Did you check if your application has the necessary permissions to create and write to the CitiesController.log file in the specified directory.

Comment: Did you configure the controller to use the channel? https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html#dic_tags-monolog

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration maybe you are not in a *dev* env:

```
monolog:
    channels:
        - deprecation 
        - cities_controller

    handlers:
        main:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
            channels: ["!event"]

        cities_controller_log:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/CitiesController.log"
            level: debug
            channels: ['cities_controller']

        console:
            type: console
            process_psr_3_messages: false
            channels: ["!event", "!doctrine", "!console"]
```